# ArrayAdapter null pointer in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

Firstly, i saw plenty of similar questions on forums but none of them have the answer to this question which works. I have tried everything. please help.

I have an arrayList which loads data from the firebase database,inside a fragment, but there is always a null pointer on this line `listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);`.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_account, container, false);

    //chat rooms code///

    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.chatRoomsList);

/////added this check////
    if(listView == null){
     Log.d("mytag1","The listview is null");
    }if(listView != null){
     Log.d("mytag2","The listview is not null");
            }

    arrayAdapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , list_of_rooms));

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    add_room.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put(room_name.getText().toString(),"");
            DBRChatrooms.updateChildren(map);

        }
    });

    DBRChatrooms.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            while (i.hasNext()){
                set.add(((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getKey());
            }

            list_of_rooms.clear();
            list_of_rooms.addAll(set);

            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),ChatRoom.class);
            intent.putExtra("room_name",((TextView)view).getText().toString() );
            intent.putExtra("user_name",name);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


    ////////////////end of chat room code//////////////


    //return view at the end
    return v;
}
```

the rest:

```
private ListView listView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
private ArrayList<String> list_of_rooms = new ArrayList<>();
private DatabaseReference DBRChatrooms = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chatrooms");
```

after reading i understand it is a problem with `getActivity()` in the arrayAdapter. But i have tried EVERYTHING!!!

> 1. getContext()
> 2. getContext().getApplicationContext()
> 3. getActivity().getApplicationContext()
> 4. v.getContext/v.getActivity
> 5. and so on, ive tried like 10 different things, always null

I even tried to put the code into onActivity created and tried everything once again still not working.

Comment: `onActivityCreated` or `onAttach` need to be used to get the Activity. But you just need a Context, not an Activity

Comment: Also, please add the stacktrace to the question

Comment: getContext does not work neither in on CreateView or onActivityCreated, still null.

Comment: Did you initialize `list_of_rooms`?

Comment: can you put a check whether your listview is null or not? I think you are using wrong id in findbyviewid.

Comment: I have added a check which always comes out false. but how can that be? i have done this in other fragments with textviews and everything works fine, all code on the net says to do it this way ?, also i have check the naming on the ''id' and it is correct

Comment: Add the stacktrace, if you want help give what people need to help you out, we need as much context as possible since we don't know your project code. Also

Comment: `getContext()` should work. How are you checking if **that** is what is null?

Answer (score 0):

I have inflated the inflater with the wrong fragment_layout....thanks for the help anyways i did learn a few things along the way

Comment: Good to hear that. Please delete your answer and question, then read [ask] and [answer]